# throwing a custom exception if a rest method(such as get,put) is hit which is still not implemented?

Tags: rest, spring-boot, exception

I am developing a Rest Spring boot application and I have my code as

1.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Initializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

 @Override
 protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder 
   application) {
       return application.sources(Initializer.class);
 }

}
```

2.
interface which implements RUD

```
@Service

public interface IProcess {

     public Object notification(Object input, Object output);

     public Object update(Object input);

     public Object read(Object input);
 }
```

3.many classes which implements IProcess

4.controller classes

5.An exception handler class with @ControllerAdvice

As of now I am implementing only POST method in Rest, Is there any generic way to throw a custom exception if a method other than POST(like get put) is hit by the clients.
If I throw servlet exception will it fulfill my requirement,If yes how do I implement it.

Comment: Assuming you are using Java 8 create a default method in the interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` in the class where you used `@ControllerAdvice`, which by default handles all known http exceptions. In your class you can override `handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported` method and return your custom message. No need to create custom exception.

Comment: Also, is there any method to throw exception if a client is calling for a specific resource or api which is still not implemented.

Comment: Yes, you can override `handleNoHandlerFoundException` method, but there is a little tweak. You have to add following in your application.properties file
`spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true`

`spring.resources.add-mappings=false`

otherwise exception won't be thrown.

Comment: will it be NoHandlerFoundException or notImplementedException. I want to handle the server side unimplemented resources, NoHandlerFoundException is for client side. Could you suggest any generic method what can be done in case of notimplementedException in my code

Comment: It will be `NoHandlerFoundException`. I don't see any usage of `NotImplementedException` in spring libraries.

Comment: Ohk, I have tried NoHandlerFoundException and it works, thanks!!

Comment: but now it catches all other exceptions too in the same method, any solution?

Comment: what do you mean by all other exceptions?

Comment: exceptions other than those coming from wrong resources/api's in uri but are related to uri

Comment: If you have overriden `handleNoHandlerFoundException` method then it will catch only `NoHandlerFoundException`. other exception won't be catched there.